# Building an SSIS EXPRESSION to test if a variable is empty

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am building an expression in expression builder to do the following, but this gives me an error:

```
@User::AccountID != ''
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
!ISNULL(@[User::AccountID])
```

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Viorel, Thanks for your reply, but i am trying to write an expression which my variable should not return blank values, i.e my variable should not be null or blank.so how do i write this piece of code into expression builder please.

Comment: Hi Viorel, ignore my previous comment,i just tested and this solves my problem, Many thanks Mate

Answer (score 0):

you can use ISNUll in expression builder :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141184.aspx

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for your reply, but i am trying to write an expression which my variable should not return blank values, i.e my variable should not be null or blank.so how do i write this piece of code into expression builder please.